# Is it possible to set the e-mail logo from update script?

Tags: email, setup-script

Does anybody know a way to set the e-mail logo (`design/email/logo`) from a data upgrade script? The config value takes the file path, but where do I have to put the file?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for how to update/save configuration
This might help:
File:

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php

```
//around line 160-version 1.9
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/config_data')
    ->setSection($section)
    ->setWebsite($website)
    ->setStore($store)
    ->setGroups($groups)
    ->save();
```

This [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474039/magento-update-store-logo-programmatically) has a lot of info on this.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in RWD theme, the path to the logo is /skin/frontend/rwd/default/images/logo.gif.

You can either move a file you added from your module to the correct path or use a file from internet with file_get_contents(http://www.url.com/icon.gif) and then move it to the correct path.